# How to change the base of logarithmic-scale plots?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica provides a score of convenient functions to make plots with various logarithmic scale axes, for instance I am using `ListLogLinearPlot` to have a discrete plot with a logarithmic x-axis and a linear y-axis.

My issue however is that I would like the x-axis to be on a binary logarithmic scale, instead of the default logarithmic scale (natural? with decimal ticks?). In particular I need 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. to be equally spaced on the x-axis to highlight the periodic nature of the function I'm plotting.

How may I proceed?

Comment: So all you want is defining your custom ticks ?

Comment: Yes, I guess :)

Comment: To be clear, all logarithmic scales are just rescalings of each other, because $\log_a x = \ln x/\ln a$. In particular, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. are already equally spaced in any logarithmic scale: try `LogLinearPlot[Cos[x], {x, 1, 16}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}, Automatic}]` and see.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @Brett: Done.${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the normal `ListPlot` and scale/label your data :

```
data = Table[{Log[x]/Log[2], Cos[x]}, {x, Range[1, 16, 0.05]}];

myTicks = {Log[#]/Log[2], #} & /@ Range[1, 16];

ListPlot[data, Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 9):

By request:

You don't need a new kind of plot function for this. The existing logarithmic plots already do exactly what you want! It doesn't matter what the base of the logarithm is: all logarithmic scales are just rescalings of each other, because $$\log_a x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$$ for any base $a$. In particular, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. are already equally spaced in any logarithmic scale. For example:

```
LogLinearPlot[Cos[x], {x, 1, 16}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Ticks -> {{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}, Automatic}]
```

[image]